# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hijri_converter'

Tags: python

I am making a project in Python and first I installed the library using Cmd:

```
    pip install -U hijri-converter
```

And then I wrote the code for converting the Gregorian year to Hijri:

```
from hijri_converter import convert

h_date = convert.Gregorian(1982, 12, 2).to_hijri()

print('Hijri', h_date)
```

But I had this problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Super\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\python.py", line 2, in <module>
    from hijri_converter import convert
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hijri_converter'
```

How can i solve it?

Comment: In *cmd* type `pip list` and check if your module is installed.

Comment: Yes, I found it:
hijri-converter 2.1.2

Comment: I use PyCharm @Marino

Comment: In PyCharm `File >> Settings >> Project: YourProject >> Interpreter` and check if in your interpreter in PyCharm there is the package that you want.

Comment: I found this:
(pip 21.1.2) and
(setuptools 57.0.0)

Comment: what should i do?

Comment: This could help: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html#install-package or use the default interpreter.

Comment: Thanks, This link helped me to solve my problem. @Marino

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by going to pyCharm:

```
 File-->Settings-->Project:pythonProject--> python Interceptor-->+(add)-->
   search about package 'hijri-converter'--> Install
```

This link helped me to solve my problem:

```
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and- 
upgrading-packages.html#packages-tool-window
```